# Server Side Rendering почему оно зовется именно так если к серверу не имеет никакого отношения

Tags: reactjs, nextjs, ssr

Объясните почему SSR зовется именно так. Например у меня есть Next.js приложение, я делаю запрос на любой сервер получаю просто какой-то json и рендерю его в своих компонентах на клиенте. Сервер не отдает мне никакой разметки, а лишь данные. Само приложение под капотом уже его оптимизирует под SEO для ботов. Почему это называют SSR-ом, если известно что Next это просто обертка над React,и это КЛИЕНТ, но никак не серверная штука. Неужели не логичнее было бы не называть так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## NE*X*T.js не путать с NE*S*T.js !

- ne**x**t - следующий, like a next generation js
- ne**s**t - гнездо

---

- https://nextjs.org
- https://nextjs.org/docs

---

- https://www.google.com/search?q=site:https://nextjs.org/docs%20ssr
- или поиском в докуменатации

---

### Two forms of Pre-rendering

- https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages
- https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#two-forms-of-pre-rendering

> Next.js has two forms of pre-rendering: Static Generation and Server-side Rendering. The difference is in when it generates the HTML for a page.
>
> Static Generation (Recommended): The HTML is generated at build time and will be reused on each request.
> Server-side Rendering: The HTML is generated on each request.

как проверить? - очень просто!
`ctrl+u`, в хроме, покажет html который пришёл с сервера, а не тот, который был сформирован яваскриптом. В случае SSG - просто посмотри в созданную фреймворком папку, поищи там html файлы соответствующие структуре твоего проекта.

### Не путай `dev`, `build` и `export`!!!

- https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cli

---

### API Routes

- https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction

> я делаю запрос на любой сервер получаю просто какой-то json и рендерю его в своих компонентах на клиенте

nextjs - это комбайн:

1. html(как на лету так и в статику)
2. стили css/sass/...
3. js/ts, react/preact
4. api, да-да, на nextjs можно организовать api и не нужно колхозить сбоку ещё один сервер!